# If $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a submanifold of dimension $d<m$ then $M$ has measure zero.

Tags: measure-theory, differential-topology

I have shown the following lemma:

If $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^1$ map, then if $A\subset U$ is a set of measure zero then $f(A)$ has measure zero.

The idea of the proof I'm following say "Let's find an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $M\subset U$ and $U\cap M$ has measure zero. So there exists $f:U\longrightarrow f(U)$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism such that $f(U\cap M)=f(U)\cap(\mathbb{R}^{d}\times\{0\}^{n-d})$ so $U\cap M=f^{-1}\Big(f(U)\cap(\mathbb{R}^{d}\times\{0\}^{n-d})\Big)$. So we can conclude with the lemma."

I understand the use of the lemma and the conclusion in general. The thing I don't understand is that the author doesn't explain how it is possible to find such a $U$ and why this $U$ would obey the local chart definition of submanifold.

Comment: I am assuming that $M$ is an embedded $d-$submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, by definition, for every $p \in M$ there is a chart of $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\chi: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \chi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ around $p$ such that $\chi(U \cap M) = \chi(U) \cap (\mathbb{R}^d \times \{0\}^{n-d})$ (this is just how an embedded submanifold is defined; if you did not define it this way, but used other theorems such as the Implicit Function Theorem, note that all of these definitions are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: Also note that the manifold may not be covered by a single chart (take for instance a sphere, it needs at least two charts). However, every embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a second countable space, so it is in particular a Lindelof space, hence it can be covered by a countable number of charts, so you can take the open set $U$ from your proof to be the union of all of those charts. Here you also use that a countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero.

Comment: Thank you very much! I hadn't understand this second countable argument before and that is what was missing, now I do understand!